# Size of the advanced write cache in the Seagate Exos 7E8 models?

Tags: hard-drive, cache

Could anybody please tell me the size of the advanced write cache in the Seagate models ST4000NM000A and ST8000NM000A?

The [datasheet](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-7-e8-msft-data-sheetDS1957-5M-2005US-en_US.pdf) just mentions: "2M internal NOR flash". This is obviously not the cache size, but rather the sort of chips they use.

[This document](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/enterprise-performance-savvio-fam/enterprise-performance-15k-hdd/_cross-product/_shared/doc/enchanced-cache-advantage-tp691.1-1610us.pdf) explains the advanced write caching, but does not tell anything about the cache size either.

Although I couldn't find that information myself, I am convinced that I just missed it or that somebody else knows about it even if it is not in the datasheets.

Comment: Have you contacted Seagate with this question?

Comment: No, I haven't. According to my experience, you have to wait several days for an answer from a manufacturer, and the answer most times is wrong because it's not the technicians who answer. I have been helped here in similar cases much quicker - there is always anybody around who has that information, or who owns the respective hardware (which I don't yet) and has measured it :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread. I’ll remove my answer, because it does not answer the question appropriately.

Comment: I wouldn't have had a problem with your answer being there :-) Eventually it would have been useful for some folks. Plus, I am still unsure if I have understood Seagate's docs about the Advanced Write Caching correctly.